# Can't create right margin on VS2010 for a second user account in my computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

To create the right margin on VS2010 for this second user account, I used exactly the same procedure I had used with the first account, that is : I created a string registry entry named "Guides" at HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Visual Studio\10.0\Text Editor with the string "RGB(100, 100, 100) 125". The registry entry was created, but when I open VS2010 for this second user, the line simply doesn't show up.

Comment: The [Productivity Power Tools Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) includes settable column guides.

Comment: But I'm almost positive I didn't use this extension when I set the margin for the first user account. Do you foresee any problem if I use this extension now ?

Comment: Well, to be safe, I'd backup the registry, remove the column guide entries, then try with the extension.  I've not tried it with multiple user accounts I don't think, but you can set multiple column guides with the extension.

Comment: @Fraser I have just used the extension and it worked all right. I'll give you the credit for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) includes settable column guides.